# $G$ be a non-nilpotent group and every $2$-maximal subgroup Per with all $3$-maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a non-nilpotent group. If $|G|=p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}r^{\gamma}$ where $p$,$q$,$r$ are primes (two of them maybe are same) such that $\alpha + \beta +\gamma \leq 3$ then every $2$-maximal subgroup of $G$ permuts with all $3$-maximal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: How solve the problem?

Comment: You ask questions about something pretty localized within advanced group theory and you given no background, no self effort, no ideas...

Comment: I read this in article. and write its directly examined. I dont what to do.

Comment: What article has this? **Hint:** Classify the 3-maximal subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha + \beta +\gamma \leq 3$ then every 3-maximal subgroup is equal $1$, so it permuts with all subgroups.

Comment: Tank you.  very good solve

Comment: @ Ebru Ardamoglo: OK, gook luck!